# Search for partial registry key in InstallShield

Tags: installation, installshield

As part of our installation procedure we have to install Adobe Acrobat XI.  According to [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/basics.html?highlight=acrobat%20guid):

> The basic formula for constructing and decoding the GUID is as follows:
>
> **Acrobat: Example: AC76BA86-1033-F400-7760-100000000002**
>
> [product family]-[language code]-[additional languages]-[product type]-
> [license type][major version][major minor version]

Since I know the key is located in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and I know the key starts with `{AC76BA86-` I would like to simply search for the key(s) that begin with that sequence so I can inspect it to determine if we need to install Acrobat.

Is there a way to do a partial registry key search in InstallShield's install script?

Comment: I caution you in bastardizing GUIDs in this way.  They are supposed to be uniquely random and this technique will not be accurate or reliable.

Comment: @Chris Adobe is bastardizing the GUIDs.  I'm slave to their screwed up system.  Not sure why working in the confines they created is worth a down vote...

Comment: Consider it being accessory after the fact.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like the best way to do this was to use `RegDBQueryKey(<registry path>, REGDB_KEYS, <returnList>)` to get a list of subkeys and then inspect each key in the list to see if it started with the partial value I was looking for.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel... :O

Answer (score 0):

Adobe is bastardizing their product codes and I really DON'T suggest playing along with that game.

However, if you read section 2.11.3 you'll see that all readers share the common UpgradeCode of A6EADE66-0000-0000-484E-7E8A45000000.

What this allows you to do is use the Upgrade Table / FindRelatedProducts to search for ProductCodes based on this UpgradeCode.  Use the "Detect Only" setting and the ProductCode found will be assigned to the Property of your choosing.

No custom actions, no bastardized ProductCode GUIDS.  Simple, easy... "It Just Works".